# tomcat - webservice times out after 60 seconds, increase connection timeout

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat

I have created some web-services in my java application which is hosted on tomcat server.
Now when that web-service is called, either from the same server or a cross domain call, it times out after 60 seconds. I want to increase this timeout to 90 seconds.
I tried setting this connectionTimeout -

```
<Connector port="5504" protocol="AJP/1.3" connectionTimeout="90000" 
redirectPort="8443" tomcatAuthentication="false" maxThreads="999" />
```

but it doesn't work. Please let me know for any further details.

Comment: I didnt think it was possible to change the browser timeout?

Comment: is it happening because of browser(chrome) timeout? How can I change and test it? any inputs?

Comment: You can't change chrome timeout. they've been ignoring this request for years.

Comment: You can change FF or IE though.

Comment: Why does the service take so long to complete?  Consider a service which starts a long running process and returns a token, then another service the client can call every few seconds to check if the long running process is complete.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are making this change in **tomcat connector**, which uses **AJP protocol**.

Instead, you should make this change in **correct connector port** which uses **HTTP protocol**.

Please refer to below setting -

```
< Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="90000" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Comment: This change doesn't work for me too (I have the same problem) ... even if we define a timeout inside ajax request ...